# how to share Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

how i can share Outlook 2007 from my office and from my home ?

we dont have Exchange server and i looking for free solution

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Live now offers an Outlook connector which, as far as I know, provides you with many of the features a home user would look for in an Outlook/Exchange setup without the cost of an Exchange server. You will, of course, have to use a Windows Live account to use this functionality, but you can do this side-by-side with your regular account.

You can download this connector tool from here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102225181033.aspx

Another alternative is to setup your own server - but it doesn't have to be Exchange. You can try Zimbra's free server, found here: http://www.zimbra.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could leave messages on your server or use imap for recieved mail. I haven't worked out how to duplicate sent mail on more than one box without the use of BCC to yourself.